# When the function is continuous, bounded of variations, absolutely continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

Let the function $f_a:[0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be defined by

$$f_a(x)=\begin{cases} x^a \cdot \cos(\frac{1}{x}) & 0 < x \leq 1 ;\\ 0 & x=0.\end{cases}$$

> Find all values $a\ge 0$ such that
>
> (a) $f_a$ is continous on $[0,1].$
>
> (b) $f_a$ is of bounded variations on $[0, 1]$
>
> (c) $f_a$ is absolutely continuous on $[0, 1]$

Do I have to show that the function is [Lipschitz continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity) for some values of $a$? How can one find these values of $a$?

Answer (score 0):

For (a), the only possible continuity issues that can occur are at $x=0$. So make sure $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+}fa(x)=fa(0)=0$. Not all values of $a$ work for this.

For $(b)$, use the fact that a Bounded variation function is differentiable almost everywhere and that the total variation equals $\int_0^1 |fa'(x)|dx$, which needs to be finite.

For $(c)$, an absolutely continuous function must satisfy the fundamental theorem of calculus: $fa(x)=\int_0^x fa'(t)dt$.

Comment: No, for (b) it is not true that the total variation equals that integral. Example:     $f(x) = 0, 0 \le x\le 1/2, f(x) = 1, 1/2<x\le 1.$ (PS: That should be $f_a$ not $fa.$)